# Return MAX(Null) as Null in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a scenario where the `max function` should work as follows in PostgreSQL:

```
select max(3,null) from table
```

should return `3`

whereas,

```
select max(null) from table
```

should return `null`.

Suggestions are welcomed!

Comment: I've removed the tag spam and just left [[tag:postgresql]], as that's what's in your title. Spamming tags doesn't help us help you and doesn't make your question more likely to get views from people who can help you, it's more likely to attract downvotes from people who are SMEs in a tagged technology that has nothing to do with the question you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

`max()` is an aggregate that works across *rows*, not columns.

You are looking for `greatest()`

```
select greatest(3,null) from table
```